# How to add custom tags in select2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In rails 4.0, I am using bootstrap's select2 plugin. In this plugin i need to add my own tags but right now custom entry is not allowing. How can i fix this issue? Which option i need to enable?

For code reference - http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

In views,

```
$('#DIV_NAME').select2({
 placeholder: "Search for a names",
 multiple: true,
 ajax: { 
   url: "autocomplete/names",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: function (term) {
     return { q: term };
   },
   results: function (data) {
     return {results: data};
   }
 }
});
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If we add the createSearchChoice option inside the select2() function then custom entry will work. Refer http://jsfiddle.net/XQ8Fw/

Script code should look like,

```
$('#DIV_USERNAME').select2({
 placeholder: "Search for a names",
 multiple: true,
 ajax: { 
   url: "autocomplete/names",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: function (term) {
     return { q: term };
   },
   results: function (data) {
     return {results: data};
   }
 },
 createSearchChoice: function (term) {
   return { id: term, text: term };
 }
});
```